# How to change second monitor display config to 'extend' in i3 window manager for ubuntu?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, display, i3-wm

So I recently installed i3 window manager on my ubuntu and loved it. It's very nice for multi-tasking. However, I've always used two monitors and my display toggle combination is function key + f1. That works in windows as well as regular ubuntu unity. But when I press function + f1 to extend display into my other monitor (as opposed to the default of duplicate), it simply types "p" and when I leave the function key, it presses enter.

How can I change the display config of my spare monitor (from duplicate to extend) in i3 window manager? If I cant use two monitors then i3 is not much of an advantage for me and I'll have to go back to regular unity which is also sad.

Comment: *i3* works very well with multiple monitors (I currently have 4), but setting up multiple displays is not within the scope of a window manager. (Unity is a desktop environment, which have a significantly broader scope).  You can set up your displays with tools like `xrandr` (command line) or `arandr` (GUI). If your layout usually does not change, you can even set up Xorg, to use both monitors correctly to begin with.